# KeyError when trying to set attribute in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, fields-attributes, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I have two input vector layers and I want to create an Output vector layer by doing some calculations. But somehow, the setAttribute method does not work.
In QGIS 2.18, I was able to set an attribute like this:

```
ID = 'id'

inEdges = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT_VECTOR_LAYER_EDGES, 
                                          context)

# get field indices for inputlayer
fieldsEdges= inEdges.fields()

idxEdgeId = fieldsEdges.indexFromName(ID)

edgeIdTrimmed = some calculation ...
(...)
newEdge = QgsFeature()    
newEdge.setAttribute(idxEdgeId, edgeIdTrimmed)   # <-- the error is here
```

But now, using QGIS 3, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 125, in processAlgorithm
>   KeyError: '0'

Any ideas on how to set an attribute value in QGIS 3?

Is there any other method to do this now?

And what does that KeyError mean exactly?

Comment: Like this?: idxEdgeId = fieldsEdges.indexFromName('edgeid');    newEdge.setAttribute(idxEdgeId, edgeIdTrimmed)

Comment: @BERA I edited my question, please have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error means that your `newEdge` object (a newly created `QgsFeature`) doesn't have attribute at key 0.

When you do `newEdge = QgsFeature()`, you create a new feature instance but this instance doesn't have any fields.

You first need to add your fields to the feature before trying to assign some values to them

```
newEdge. = QgsFeature()
newEdge.setFields(inEdges.fields())
newEdge.setAttribute(idxEdgeId, edgeIdTrimmed)
```

Alternatively, you can use this syntax:

```
newEdge[idxEdgeId] = edgeIdTrimmed
```

Or even more concise:

```
newEdge[ID] = edgeIdTrimmed
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: May I ask you how to add a field to the QgsFeature? (In addition to the line newEdge.setFields(inEdges.fields())

Comment: Please ask another question for this issue with more information about what you're trying to do. Note that if you want to save a feature in a layer, the fields of both must be consistent.